# Difference between bin's java.exe and JRE's 'java.exe'

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I have a confusion which interpreter is used to execute Java programs as I can see two *java.exe*, one inside the *bin* folder and the other inside JRE's *bin* folder.

I want to add some details to clear my query:

Suppose Java is installed in *C:\Program Files\Java\Jdk1.6*. Now, in this directory there is the *jre* folder, *bin* folder, and other folders as well, but let’s concentrate on these two. This *..\jre\bin* folder contains *java.exe* and the *..\bin* folder also contains *java.exe*. So, my concern is: Which Java interpreter is used to execute Java programs?

Comment: I suggest set classpath for jdk/bin than jre/bin; if you have installed JDK. Both java.exe will do the same job for you but jdk has more executable for java development like javac.exe.

Answer (score 9):

From the Java SE installation notes:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/install-windows-142126.html#private

> Installing the JDK installs a private Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) and optionally a public copy. The **private JRE** is required to run the tools included with the JDK. It has no registry settings and is contained entirely in a jre directory (typically at `C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0\jre`) whose location is known only to the JDK. On the other hand, the **public JRE** can be used by other Java applications, is contained outside the JDK (typically at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0`), is registered with the Windows registry (at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft), can be removed using Add/Remove Programs, might or might not be registered with browsers, and might or might not have java.exe copied to the Windows system directory (making it the default system Java platform or not).

So I think you should use executables from the /bin directory when executing Java programs.

Answer (score 1):

JRE: Java Runtime Environment. It is basically the Java Virtual Machine where your Java programs run on. It also includes browser plugins for Applet execution.

JDK: It's the full featured Software Development Kit for Java, including JRE, and the compilers and tools (like JavaDoc, and Java Debugger) to create and compile programs.

Usually, when you only care about running Java programs on your browser or computer you will only install JRE. It's all you need. On the other hand, if you are planning to do some Java programming, you will also need JDK.

Sometimes, even though you are not planning to do any Java Development on a computer, you still need the JDK installed. For example, if you are deploying a WebApp with JSP, you are technically just running Java Programs inside the application server. Why would you need JDK then? Because application server will convert JSP into Servlets and use JDK to compile the servlets. I am sure there might be more examples.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But this is not what i want to know. Let me explain u in more details.....                                      Suppose java is installed in C:\Program Files\Java\Jdk1.6           Now, in this directory there is jre folder , bin folder & other folders as well but lets concentrate on these two. This ..\jre\bin folder contains java.exe & ..\bin folder also contains java.exe So, my concern is that which java interpreter is used to execute java program.                                                            I hope this will help u to better understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [java.home](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.home&trusted=on&format=TSV) property.  It should point to one or the other.  Here I get..

```
Name        Value
java.home   C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check filesize and filedate of your `java.exe` files.

It should be the same.

In my opinion the JDK is a kind of *superset* of the JRE. So if you need further tools for building or compiling, the JDK is the place to go. Otherwise you can use the JRE

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the JRE, then java.exe should be here
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

If you installed the JDK, then java.exe will be in two places:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin

If you install both the jdk and jre, you can compare C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre with C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin and they will be almost or exactly identical, and you can use the java.exe from either one, but I think most people will use the one in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin

Comment: @Daniel no this is false.  if you don't believe me you need to download the latest jre from oracle and install it so you can see what it does

Comment: But it is wrong if you download the JDK, what I assumed would everyone use here.

Comment: when he first asked it, it seemed like he was talking about the jre, I modified the answer to include the jdk

Comment: --1: In this case I can aggree.

Answer (score 0):

For the paths that you provide, I suppose that you're on Windows.

Now, which `java.exe` are you using?

It may depends on what you're executing. If you're running an *applet*, a *jar* or *Java Web Start*, you'll use the `java.exe` that is in the `bin` directory pointed by your `PATH` environment variable. Besides, if you open a console and execute `java` you'll run the `java.exe` that is pointed by your 'PATH' variable.
If you're running a `.bat` file, check if it's used a different environment variable. It's common to use `JAVA_HOME` or `JAVA_SDK`.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, I can say **there isn't any difference**, apart from the purpose of jdk and jre. **Both java.exe are the same**.