# Java Tutorial Security trail - updating java.security file doesn't work

Tags: java, security, exception

I'm going through the Java Tutorial Security trail but I'm stuck at the "See the Policy File Effects" lesson ([See the Policy File Effects lesson link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep4.html). I can make approach 1 work.  This makes me think that I haven't typo'd my policy and signed jar file.  Approach 2, editing the java.security file, isn't working.

I'm working on Windows 7 using Java 7 (installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67). I do not have a .java.policy file (although I did try this).

Here's the exception

```
$ java -Djava.security.manager -cp sCount.jar Count C:/tstsecdata/data
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\tstsecdata\data" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Count.main(Count.java:48)
```

What I've tried.

1. I noticed that I had several JDKs installed.  I uninstalled all and then re-installed jdk1.7.0_67.
2. I noticed that 2 jre's are installed.  One is Java\jdk1.7.0_61\jre.  The other is Java\jre7.  I found an explanation for this at [Oracle JDK installs two JREs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896541/oracle-jdk-installs-two-jres).  So I edited both java.security files and added the following line to each (after the policy.url.2 entry).

   policy.url.3=file:/c:/tstsec/exampleraypolicy

FWIW, here's the policy file:

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Tue Jun 02 09:39:05 EDT 2015*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

keystore "file:/C:/tstsec/exampleraystore", "jks";

grant signedBy "susan" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\tstsecdata\\*", "read";
};
```

3. I tried making a copy of my edited java.security file and putting it in my /Users/ folder as ".java.policy".

My workstation is administered by the IT dept although I do have admin privileges.  Is there some Windows 7 policy that is messing with me?