# What is the java.exe difference from jdk to (included) jre?

Tags: java

So, I had always thought there was no difference between the `java.exe` located in the `jdk\bin` and that in the `jdk\jre\bin` folders.  Apparently, that is not the case, certainly not with java8 anyway.

I was testing the maverick ssh library and found that it would not auto-negotiate an encryption cipher from the list offered by the sshd server when using the `java.exe` from `jdk\bin`.  Changing the java.exe used to that from the jre supplied with jdk (in the `jdk\jre\bin` folder) let the test app work fine.

So... what could possibly explain the difference - why would one `java.exe` work and the other not, if they are both the same?

They appear the same on the surface:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20>dir bin\java.exe

08/22/2014  03:35 PM           190,856 java.exe

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20>dir jre\bin\java.exe

08/22/2014  03:35 PM           190,856 java.exe
```

But must be different under the hood:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20>diff bin\java.exe jre\bin\java.exe
Files bin\java.exe and jre\bin\java.exe differ
```

**EDIT**:

I did review the question which is suggested as a duplicate, however it did not address my question.

The versions of the binaries appear the same:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20>bin\java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20>jre\bin\java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

I did not adjust the classpath or anything else on my commandline, other than the path to java.exe.

Compared the two using WinMerge... there are a few diffs nr the start and end (moreso) of the two files. All binary gobble-de-gook to me.

[image]

Comment: There are maybe some different [header information](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#File_Format).

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between bin's java.exe and jre's java.exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936788/difference-between-bins-java-exe-and-jres-java-exe)

Comment: @angstadt530: *Possibly*, but Jon's pointed out that his files are actually different, which that question doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re using that library and getting different results, that's almost certainly not anything to do with `java.exe`, but something to do with the classpath and jars used by the JDK install vs. the JRE install.

Re your different files, it's not just you: I dug up a Windows 8.1 machine with (an old copy of) Oracle's Java8 on it, and it's the same thing: Sizes, dates, and versions match, contents don't *quite*. This isn't true of my Linux box with Oracle's Java8 on it, where the `jdk/bin/java` and `jdk/jre/bin/java` files are identical (and not just symlinked). My guess is it relates to optimization defaults, but doesn't relate to your ssh library issue.

Comment: Well, not like it would be the first time optimizations have broken something.

Comment: Accepting this as it appears to be the most reasonable proposal.